# How to automate WEBVIEW in Native Android application?

Tags: automated-testing, android

[image]

How to automate WEBVIEW content in Android Automation ?

In above attached Image i want to verify Bold and Underlined content.

Can anyone help me regarding it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Appium or Selendroid to automate this WebView, you may simply use the inspector to locate the element/elements used for Bold/underlined text. Once you have located the element, simply use getText method to get the text inside that web element.

Comment: I use SEETEST automation tool and i am only able to find LINK and HEADING using it.

Comment: Haven't used seetest much... however I think you can select the zone for bold/underlined text and use getText method. Here is a link that may help https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/SA/GetText

Comment: Yup its giving Text in String. but i need to verify BOLD etc. content

Comment: In that case I would suggest you used xpath to verify if the text is inside the bold tag. use xpath to locate the element and traverse from parent node to child node which has bold tag... for eg, you may write xpath on similar lines, xpath= //div[@id='abc']/b[contains(text(),'automation engineer')] . I am assuming the text is inside a div tag and uses bold option in the example... if it uses strong attribute, you may modify the xpath and write it on the basis on attribute

Comment: Appreciated answer but its a Android Automation Native Application so no div i found in it and I am only able to find VIEWS

Comment: That was just an example. For example, if you want to know the ID of an element The command should look something like this: ElementGetProperty("", "", index, "id") And so on for other properties available on the object spy like "hidden", "onScreen", "parentHidden", "bold", "strong" etc... hope this helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47315/discussion-between-gaurav-and-bountyhunter).